# Websphere 7 download free

Tags: download, websphere

I want to download Websphere application server developer version 7 for solaris. I have some queries.

1. Is it available freely. If yes please provide the appropriate link.
2. If its not free then how can I buy that?

Answer (score 16):

The community edition is downloaded from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasce/)

The free developer edition of WAS can be downloaded: [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasdevelopers/index.html)

Community edition is not the same as full WebSphere, but can be deployed in production.

Developer Edition is the same as the full commercial WAS but is licenced only for use by a developer on their desktop. If you are intending to develop for full WAS I recommend you get this version.

Comment: Is WebSphere for Developers available for Solaris OS? I have tried to download from following page: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27012958#anchor_Solarisx86 but without luck.

Comment: @dyna Maybe this is a dumb question but what's stopping me from using the developer edition for production ? Is it illegal ?

Comment: Ced: yes contravenes the license agreement, but so far as I know (no longer work for IBM) not policed by a licence-manager. Be aware of the IBM software audit process. http://www.pcworld.com/article/2088360/how-to-survive-an-ibm-software-license-audit.html